# Constraints don't seem to work in cells inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints

as the title says I'm currently having some problems in setting up constraints of elements in a cell, which is inside a UITableView. In this cell there are one UIImageView, one UIButton and two UILabels. I've set up the ImageView to be vertically aligned at the center of the cell and to be attached to the left edge of the screen. I've also set up two constraints for its width and height. This works fine so far, both in the storyboard and in the build. What I can't seem to make work are the constraints for the other elements. I've tried different combinations of constraints, but all of them had the same result: the cell seems fine in the storyboard, but when I run the app, the three elements (label, label, button) are shrunk in the top left corner of the cell, above the UIImageView.

[The storyboard looks fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kInxd.png)

[The app, instead, is all messed up with the elements shrunk in the top left corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyvGp.png)

I feel like there's something that I'm getting wrong, but I've already watched and read so many things about constraints and still can't make this one work. I've found this other question here on StackOverflow, but the guy sets up constraints programmatically. In his case, the issue was about the way contentView behaves inside a cell.

I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction, since I can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: can you describe the constraints of other elements ? it seems that you have missing constraints.

Comment: Show us a print screen of the constraints or the size inspector in the right sidebar on each element that lists the applied constraints

Comment: @Edoardo - Making constrains in storyboard,You can take one objective as initiative, and you can make based on that,You can try to give maximum 4 constrains for one object.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I would have liked to, but I can't because of my low karma (this is my first or second post here on SO). I'll try to describe what I've done. 
The ImageView is centered vertically in the container, in attached to the left edge of the container and has constraints for both width and height. The button is attached to the right side of the image, to the bottom and to the right of the container, and has fixed height. The other labels are attached to the left side of the image and have constraints for their width and for their vertical distance. The storyboard doesn't show errors.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the relevant constraints from the interface builder and share it?

Comment: My app is currently doing the exact same thing. If I run it without any constraints, then it looks great on my device. However, if I add one constraint, then that element immediately moves to the top left of the cell. Have not been able to figure out what is causing it. Did you every figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **UIStackView** here. For example you can put your other three elements into the stack(excluding **UIImageView**). After put **UIImageView** and StackView with these three elements to another StackView. After this you can pin this big StackView to edges of your cell and change its properties (Alignment and Distribution) in Attributes Inspector the way you like

Comment: I've just tried and it's still messed up in the exact same way. Everything is shrunk in the top left corner and nothing changes. That looks actually so strange to me. Thanks for your suggestion anyways.